# Handling BindException in a SpringBoot app with global exception handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I have a controller with a post request. I'm trying to validate the POJO with a simple NotNull annotation. I'm using a ControllerAdvice to handle the exceptions.

```
@PostMapping("/something")
public MyResponse post(@Valid MyRequest request) {
   // nevermind...
}
```

```
public class MyRequest {
  @NotNull
  private Integer something;
  // Getters setters nevermind...
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = BindException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(...);
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to use this but when I start the application I got the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.validation.BindException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.liligo.sponsoredads.controller.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleBindException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
```

So I would like to create my own handler for the BindExceptions but when I create the ExceptionHandler for the BindException class the spring app is not starting. If I comment out the handleBindException method the app starts up and if a BindException occurs it just return a 400 and log out the error but nothing is sent back as the response body.

What could be the solution to create a custom handler for BindExceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that the problem is because the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler already has a method to handle the BindExceptions. That means you cannot "override" the exception handling for that. That also the case for many exceptions (see in the class ResponseEntityExceptionHandler:106).
So if you want to create your own Bind Exception handler then you need to override the method that handles it in the superclass.
It looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
                                                         HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return handleExceptionInternal(...);
}
```

With it, you can return anything that you need. So I found only this solution, if anyone knows any other please don't hesitate to write here :)